# How do I limit a user to enter any 4 digit combination including combinations beginning with 0 and excluding all other characters in C?

Tags: c, validation, input, integer, scanf

I'm writing a program in C where I want a user to be able to change their existing PIN, the only requirement to allow pin to be able to be changed is that user must enter a new PIN that must be a 4 digit number of any combination including those that start with 0 (eg: `0000`, `0297`, `0005`, `0050`...) and the PIN must not contain any alphabetical characters

they must then re-enter their new PIN to confirm it
if re-entered pin matches the first newly entered pin then users will be assigned new pin.

```
if (temppin1 == temppin2)
```

I have initialised the temp pins to be an `int`, for comparison arguments like above.

here is a snippet of my code

```
        case '2':
           //program asks user to enter their new PIN.
           printf("Enter your new PIN:\n");
           scanf("%04d", &temp_pin1);
           //program asks user to re-enter their new PIN.
           printf("Please re-enter to confirm your new PIN:\n");
           scanf("%04d", &temp_pin2);

           //if the re-entered pin matches the temp_pin1 then then the program will assign the new PIN to the users actual_pin.
           if (temp_pin1 == temp_pin2 && (isalpha(temp_pin1) == 0) && (temp_pin1 >= 1000 && temp_pin1 < 9999)) {
                printf("\n\n New PIN has been confirmed\n\n");
                actual_pin = temp_pin1;
           }
           //if the user input as letter, some other character or a number outside of the four digit including number starting with 0 range the program will give an appropriate error message.
           else if ((temp_pin1 != temp_pin2) && ((temp_pin1 > 1000) && (temp_pin1 < 9999))) {
                printf("error: your new PIN didn't match\n");
                printf("We couldn't confirm your new PIN\n\n");
           }
           //all possible 4 digit are between this range and if a number is entered outside this range the user will be given an appropriate error message.
           else if ((temp_pin1 < 1000) || (temp_pin1 > 9999)) {
                printf("error: Your new pin didn't meet our 4 digit PIN criteria\n\n");
           }
           break;
```

I figured out you can use `isalpha() == 0` to make sure the user input doesn't accept alphabetical numbers, I also figured out the range of of all possible 4 digit numbers that begin with (`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`). the last part I just need to figure out is how to let user 4 digit number that can begin with 0 (eg: `0000`, `0297`, `0005`, `0050`...) and store it with the initial `0`, I know C will take inputed int numbers beginning with `0` as a null value so but I also need to compare the two variable and see if they are the same, maybe a different datatype needs to be used... but I'm not sure.

Any help, or insight into what I can do to solve this tricky validation problem would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf` for this. Use `fgets` and then parse the line yourself possibly using `sccanf`.

Comment: You are storing the user pin is in 'actual_pin' variable which is an integer. So obviously leading zero has no importance. So if actual_pin value is 5, it means user input 0005 (implicit).  In case you need to display actual_pin later in your program, you add leading zero using same formatter (%04d) in printf..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` can be done using `%n` to capture the number of characters processed. This will reject inputs of `12`, `005` or `12345`. `%d` will only accept digits so `abc` will be rejected. No need for `isalpha`.
Clean the input with `getchar`. If any characters other than a newline are in the input stream. the input is rejected to prevent an input of `1234abc`.

`fgets` can also be used to read a line. `strspn` will count the consecutive matching characters. The matching digits must be followed by a newline or the input is rejected.

Normally DO NOT MIX FGETS and SCANF. This uses both and will work only because after `scanf`, `getchar` cleans the input stream of pending characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char line[100] = "";
    int temp_pin1 = 0;
    int temp_pin2 = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int clean = 0;

    do {
        if ( temp_pin1 != temp_pin2) {
            printf ( "PIN does not match. re-enter PIN\n");
        }
        do {
            if ( clean) {
                printf ( "try again\n");
            }
            end = 0;
            start = 0;
            printf("Enter your new PIN:\n");
            fflush ( stdout);
            if ( ( result = scanf ( " %n%d%n", &start, &temp_pin1, &end))) {
                if ( 4 != end - start) {
                    result = 0;
                }
            }
            while ( ( clean = getchar ( ))) {
                if ( '\n' == clean) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    result = 0;//found trailing characters
                }
                if ( EOF == clean) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "End Of File\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        } while ( 1 != result);

        clean = 0;
        do {
            if ( clean) {
                printf ( "try again\n");
            }
            index = 0;
            clean = 0;
            printf("Please re-enter to confirm your new PIN:\n");
            fflush ( stdout);
            if ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
                index = strspn ( line, "0123456789");
                clean = 1;
            }
            else {
                fprintf ( stderr, "End Of File\n");
                return 1;
            }
        } while ( 4 != index || '\n' != line[index]);
        sscanf ( line, "%d", &temp_pin2);
    } while ( temp_pin1 != temp_pin2);

    printf ( "new PIN: %04d\n", temp_pin1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran this code and it works, flawlessly and does everything I want it to do, you are legend beyond our times, I'm going to try use the logic and implement it into my program,Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fully functional; there is no need for any change. 0008 is same as 8, as it is stored internally as an integer. There will not be any problem during comparison. If needed, you can change int to char[4] (or char[5] for the terminating null byte if you want to process it like a string) if necessary. Read the pin using

```
char temp_pin1[5];
scanf("%4s", temp_pin1);
```

or

```
char temp_pin1[4];
scanf("%c%c%c%c", &temp_pin1[0], &temp_pin1[1], &temp_pin1[2], &temp_pin1[3]);
```

And then check if the characters are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Testing `isalpha(temp_pin1)` makes no sense: you are testing if the PIN number is the ASCII code for a letter, which is irrelevant: `0065` is a valid PIN, but also happens to be the ASCII code for `'A'`.

You should just read the PIN as an `int` an verify that it is in the range `0` to `9999` inclusive:

```
        case '2':
           //program asks user to enter their new PIN.
           printf("Enter your new PIN:\n");
           if (scanf("%d", &temp_pin1) != 1 || temp_pin1 < 0 || temp_pin1 > 9999) {
               printf("invalid PIN: must be 4 digits\n");
               break;
           }
           //program asks user to re-enter their new PIN.
           printf("Please re-enter to confirm your new PIN:\n");
           if (scanf("%d", &temp_pin2) != 1 || temp_pin1 != temp_pin2) {
               printf("error: your new PIN didn't match\n");
               printf("We couldn't confirm your new PIN\n\n");
               break;
           }
           printf("\n\n New PIN has been confirmed\n\n");
           actual_pin = temp_pin1;
           break;
```